# My hosting server does not support .NET framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting

When I upload my folder to my hosting I get an error like `Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'` . I have read on the internet that this is due to app pool. I can fix this on my local IIS by setting the required app pool. Is there a way to modify the web.config file so that this error does not occur?

Comment: Please ask your provider to setup .net 4 for you. if your provider doesnt support .net 4, you may check other hosting provider that support .net 4.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your hosting company support the targeted .NET version and if you set it for your site. If not and you are using shared hosting then you should ask the host to install it for you but some hosts will refuse such request, if you use VPS or Dedicated hosting then you could install it on the server.